# Replace word in string, but not if it has custom string before?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

How can I replace a word in a string, but only if that word does not have a string of my choosing before ?

Example we have the following strings:

```
String 1: long boat

String 2: jet boat
```

How can I replace the word "boat" but only if the previous word is not "jet" ?

I am using PHP and so far I came up with this.

```
preg_replace("/[\s+]boat/", "", $string);
```

This works for words that have "jet" after:

```
preg_replace("/[\s+]boat(?!\s*jet)/", "", $string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lookbehind**

Use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~(?<!jet )boat~', '', $yourstring);
```

**Explanation**

- The negative lookbehind `(?<!jet )` asserts that what precedes the current position is not `jet`
- `boat` matches the literal chars
- We replace with the empty string

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: What if there is more than one space appears after jet?

Comment: +1 Thank you this works! Thanks for the reference also, I did not knew it is called "lookbehind" and could not find a solution anywhere. New to regex :P